# Searching and selecting an option value in a HTML select element

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I need your help.

I am a newbie to javascript and I am unsure as to how I would go about searching for a specified option in a select box and then selecting it

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>

</head>

<body>

<select id="select1">
   <option value="apples">apples</option>
   <option value="oranges">oranges</option>
   <option value="bananas">bananas</option>
   <option value="mangos">mangos</option>
   <option value="pears">pears</option>
 </select>

</body>

</html>
```

ie.

```
lookup("select1","mangos")
```

javascript logic:

```
function lookup("selectid","stringtosearchfor") {

look through the selected "selectid" and find the string "mangos"

if found { select mangos from the select box }

}
```

How do you code that ?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Are you trying to get the element itself or what exactly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is easier than you think... try:

```
document.getElementById('select1').value = 'mangos';
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function lookup(id, value)
{
    var ret = undefined;

    if(document.getElementById(id) != undefined)
    {
        var options = document.getElementById(id).childNodes;

        for(i = 0; i < options.length; i++)
        {
            if(options[i].value == value)
            {
                ret = options[i];
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    return ret;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Via Jquery:

```
$('#select1').val('mangos');
```